# Eliminating DEPRECATED errors form the error_log in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting

Is it possible to eliminate DEPRECATED messages from the PHP error_log?

I know I can use

```
~E_DEPRECATED
```

to keep them from the display but is there any way to keep them out of the error_log as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bug: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48843

The right way to keep that message out of your logs is to replace the deprecated code :)

Comment: Thanks...
I, like the bug poster, am expecting the errors.  I have a long list to tend to, but that's down on my to-do list at the moment ;-)